# Parent iFrame Communication in Dynamics CRM

Tags: javascript, iframe, dynamics-crm, postmessage

I created a HTML web resource on a form. This HTML generates an iFrame dynamically. It also needs to listen to requests coming from the child iFrame and blink/stop blinking the browser's tab.

Our dynamics CRM is over HTTP and the iFrame is over HTTPS.

This is the HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" >

        // Global variables for tab blinking
        var _title = "";
        var _flipper = 0;
        var _isActive = false;
        

        window.onload = function () {
            var src = getIframeSrc();
            addIFrame(src);
            attachListeners();         
        }

        var addIFrame = function(src) {
            var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
            iframe.src = src;
            iframe.setAttribute("style", "width: 100%; height: 100%;");
            document.body.appendChild(iframe);
        }
        var messageHandler = function (event) {
            debugger;
            if (event && event.data) {
                var d = JSON.parse(event.data);
                if (d.active == 0) {
                    _isActive = false;
                }
                else {
                    _isActive = true;
                }

                blinkTab();
            }
            else {
                console.log("data not found in postMessage");
            }
        }

        var attachListeners = function () {
            try {
                if (window.addEventListener) {
                    window.addEventListener("message", messageHandler, false);
                }
                else {
                    window.attachEvent("onmessage", messageHandler);
                }
            }
            catch (e) {
                console.log("problem in listening.");
            }
        }

        var getIframeSrc = function () {
            var url = "https://path/to/iframe"; // iframe is https
            var st_val = parent.Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_st").getValue();
            if (st_val) {
                url += "?st=" + st_val;
            }
            return url;
        }

        var blinkTab = function () {
            if (_isActive) {
                if (_title == "")
                    _title = top.document.title;

                setTimeout(() => {
                    if (_flipper == 0) {
                        _flipper = 1;
                        top.document.title = "*******************";
                        blinkTab();
                    } else {
                        _flipper = 0;
                        top.document.title = _title;
                        blinkTab();
                    }
                }, 1000);

            } else {
                top.document.title = _title;
            }
        }
    </script>


</body>
</html>
```

Inside the iFrame, which we do not have access to as it is in another domain, the `postMessage` API is used to send data to the parent HTML.

Code inside the iFrame is:

```
window.top.postMessage(JSON.stringify({active: 1}), "*")
```

but the `debugger` inside `messageHandler` will not be hit.

The checkbox "restrict cross-frame scripting" for the HTML web resouce is unmarked.

We are using Dynamics CRM v8.1 on-premise.

**Edit: Problem solved. The issue was that the listener was attached to the `window` object whereas it should have been attached to `window.top` instead.**

Comment: Why are you trying to call this on `top` or `parent`? You should be calling this on the window object of the iframe itself, you want _that_ to send a message to a different window, that of the main page.

Comment: Because the iFrame in hosted inside the HTML. the HTML is its parent, is it not?

Comment: You want to send a message _from_ the iframe to the parent, so you need to call `postMessage` _on_ the iframe's own `window` instance.

Comment: I still don't understand why would I use the window object itself instead of window.parent? In this example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20143479/parent-iframe-postmessage-communication they also use window.parent and it works just fine

Comment: Then the window _sending_ the message, would also be the one "listening" to _receive_ that message - can't see how that is supposed to make much sense in the first place.

Comment: So what you are saying is that in my HTML I have two seperated window objects - one of the parent HTML and one of the iFrame, whereas in the example I provided they have only one window object. Did I understand this correctly?

Comment: Not sure where you got that from. The purpose of `postMessage` is to establish a communication _between_ windows.

Comment: Alright well then I guess I still don't quite understand why I would use window.postMessage and they'd use parent.postMessage? As far as I can tell our examples are practically the same with the exception of them also sending requests from the parent to the iFrame

Comment: It might work in both ways, assuming access to the parent window is actually given, but it makes little sense to me, logically, to do it _that_ way. The iframe has something to communicate here, so _it_ should be the one _sending_ this message.

Comment: I have no idea what _'The checkbox "restrict cross-frame scripting" for the HTML web resouce is unmarked.'_ is supposed to mean in the first place here, but I am guessing the whole issue might have something to do with that CRM context you are in there; so maybe I'd try to set this up using stand-alone documents completely outside of the CRM context first, and see that you get that working. Then you can try and investigate what additional settings/configuration within your CRM might interfere with this.